# changing Jtable row font to bold

Tags: java, swing, fonts, formatting, jtable

I had a JTable in java and i want to know how i can modify the font to bold depending on a integer value. I Currently have this table and i want to change the font of the row depending on the number of people in the coach. i am still new to swing and i have no idea about how to do this. i need a solution that would do something like:

```
 if (num_people >17 && num_people<26){
     //change row font to bold
}
```

this is an example of what i would need if following the image i have below of what i already have:

[image: What i have so far in my program]

Link to my current code:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/015022f7ad55ff9664e2edaea6a58d5a

Comment: Same answer that is given every day, twice or more on some. Use a renderer. *"want to change the font of the row depending on the number of people in the coach. i am still new to swing and i have no idea about how to do this"* Which is why you should be doing the [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) tutorial, which you obviously have not done.

Comment: @AndrewThompson the hoe to use tables tutorial does not show how to make text bold. i tried to find it but i couldn't. mbye you could point it out for me

Comment: Oh for crying out loud.. It does not show every variant of doing every possible thing because you're supposed to be able to use different parts of the API for different things! Are you sure you're cut out for programming?

Answer (score 6):

```
public class CellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
        int column) {
    super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

    if (value>17 value<26) {
        this.setValue(table.getValueAt(row, column));
        this.setFont(this.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
    }
    return this;
}
}
```

this is how a cell renderer would look like with bold font. i didn't test it. you call `table.getColumnModel().getColumn(x).setCellRenderer(new CellRenderer());` after you initialized your JTable and call it for every column you want that font to apply.

Comment: where do i paste this?

Comment: @SakshamGoyal new class and use it with `table.getColumnModel().getColumn(x).setCellRenderer(new CellRenderer());` where x is the column you want to change. if its every columns, iterate over them

Comment: please remember i am new to swing, if you look at my code i put at the top, can you please use that and tell me how to do it. i have never used swing before. maybe if you could edit your answer so i know how to do this.

Comment: can you please upvote me question? i dont have much reputation.

Comment: Right now i am taking a break and doing something else right now. i will come back to this program later

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Table Row Rendering](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/). It shows how to apply rendering to a given row in a table, by overriding the `prepareRenderer(....)` method. This is especially useful when you use different renderers for each column.

You really should be using different renderers for certain columns in your table. Some cell should render strings and some should render number values which typically display the values as right aligned.

You can also check out [Table Format Renderers](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/11/table-format-renderers/) which makes is easier to create custom renders with special formatting of the data.

Comment: can you please look at my code and show me? i am new to swing so i dont know how to do it

Comment: @SakshamGoyal, I did show you working code. Follow the link and download the working code examples. Take some time to understand how they work and then customize the logic for your exact requirement. `i am new to swing` - and you learn by trying. You will rarely find code examples that do exactly what you want. So you need to understand the concept and then customize the code that people give you for examples.