# How can I make certain rows bold in Jtable not depending from the value using custom cell renderer

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm learning to program in high school. The first language I'm now learning is Java.

I'm working on a project to make something like mail and I have created a `JTable` to display all the messages. The table consists of 3 columns which are for date, title, and sender. Everything is working perfectly on. Now I'm trying to make the unread messages displayed in bold. The messages are objects and are stored in an `ArrayList`. I've been searching a lot on this topic but haven't found a lot that can help me.

Here is the message code as an object:

```
public class mail {

    String sender;
    String title;
    String text;
    String date;
    boolean read=false;

    
    public mail(String sender, String title, String text,String date) {
        super();
        this.sender = sender;
        this.title = title;
        this.text = text;
        this.date = date;
        
    }
}
```

Every mail has a `boolean` to know if it was read or not.
I need a way to import the `boolean` array in the Renderer class and based on the data in him to make some rows bold.

Here's the main code:

```
public class menu extends JFrame {

static ArrayList<user> a=new ArrayList<user>();
static int indx;

public static ArrayList<user> getA() {
    return a;
}

public static void setA(ArrayList<user> a) {
    menu.a = a;
}

public static int getB() {
    return indx;
}

public static void setB(int b) {
    menu.indx = b;
}

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTable table_1;
private JTable table;
private JTable table_2;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                menu frame = new menu(a,indx);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}


public menu(ArrayList<user> users,int index) {
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");  
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();  
    String date=dtf.format(now);
    
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 651, 450);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    
    //Login
    JButton btnLogout = new JButton("logout");
    btnLogout.setBounds(10, 377, 89, 23);
    btnLogout.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bye B1t4");
            login log=new login(users);
            log.setLocationRelativeTo(null);        //sets the window in the middle
            log.setVisible(true);
            dispose();
        }
    });
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    contentPane.add(btnLogout);
    
    //writing
    JButton btnWrite = new JButton("write");
    btnWrite.setBounds(10, 343, 89, 23);
    btnWrite.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            write obj=new write(users,index);
            obj.setLocationRelativeTo(null); //sets the window in the middle
            obj.setVisible(true);
            dispose();
        }
    });
    contentPane.add(btnWrite);
    
    //account view
    JButton btnMyacc = new JButton("myacc");
    btnMyacc.setBounds(10, 273, 89, 23);
    btnMyacc.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            myInfo obj=new myInfo(users,index);
            obj.setLocationRelativeTo(null); //sets the window in the middle
            obj.setVisible(true);
            dispose();
        }
    });
    contentPane.add(btnMyacc);
    
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();                 
    scrollPane.setToolTipText("");                              
    scrollPane.setViewportBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
    scrollPane.setBounds(109, 51, 516, 349);
    contentPane.add(scrollPane);

    int inboxSize=users.get(index).inbox.size();

    String Object [][]= new String[inboxSize][4];    //we create an 2 dimensional string array called Object with the size of the users inbox
    boolean read []=new boolean[inboxSize]; // this is the boolean array with the logic I want to use
    
    for(int i=0;i<inboxSize;i++) {                                                                                  
        if(users.get(index).inbox.get(i).read) {                        
            read[i]=false;
        }else { 
            read[i]=true;
        }
        Object[i][0]= users.get(index).inbox.get(i).date;       //date recieved
        Object[i][1]= users.get(index).inbox.get(i).sender;     //mail sender       
        Object[i][2]= users.get(index).inbox.get(i).title;      //mail title                
    }

    table_2 = new JTable();
    table_2.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    table_2.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
        Object,                                                                         
        new String[] {
            "Date", "Sender", "Title"
        }
    ));
    scrollPane.setViewportView(table_2);
    //balding
    table_2.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new CellRenderer());
    table_2.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(new CellRenderer());
    table_2.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellRenderer(new CellRenderer());
    
    //reading
    JButton btnRead = new JButton("read");                                              
    btnRead.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            users.get(index).inbox.get(table_2.getSelectedRow()).read=true; 
            read obj=new read(users,index,table_2.getSelectedRow());
            obj.setLocationRelativeTo(null);        //sets the window in the middle
            obj.setVisible(true);
            dispose();
        }
    });
    btnRead.setBounds(10, 307, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnRead);
}

public class CellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    //dont know ho to initialize
    boolean a;
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
            int column) {
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        //if ( /* i don't know how */ ) {
            this.setValue(table.getValueAt(row, column));
            this.setFont(this.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
        //}
        return this;
    }
}
}
```

Тhe design for the cell renderer is similar to this article. [changing Jtable row font to bold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41102850/changing-jtable-row-font-to-bold)

Comment: To highlight an entire row check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696366/change-color-of-jtable-row-based-on-the-value-of-the-database/29702874#29702874. Also: 1) don't use a 2D array to hold the data. Just create an empty DefaultTableModel. Then in your loop you use the `addRow(...)` method of the DefaultTableModel. This will allow you to create a model with a dynamic number of rows. 2) don't use a null layout and setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

Comment: Thank you very much. I solved the problem pretty easily with that.